# How to md5 all columns regardless of type

Tags: sql, postgresql, md5, plpgsql

I would like to create a sql query (or plpgsql) that will md5() all given rows regardless of type. However, below, if one is null then the hash is null:

```
UPDATE thetable 
    SET hash = md5(accountid || accounttype || createdby || editedby);
```

I am later using the hash to compare uniqueness so null hash does not work for this use case.

The problem was the way it handles concatenating nulls. For example:

```
thedatabase=# SELECT accountid || accounttype || createdby  || editedby 
                 FROM thetable LIMIT 5;  

1Type113225  
<NULL>
2Type11751222 
3Type10651010 
4Type10651
```

I could use coalesce or CASE statements if I knew the type; however, I have many tables and I will not know the type ahead of time of every column.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There is much more elegant solution for this.

In Postgres, using table name in `SELECT` is permitted and it has type `ROW`. If you cast this to type `TEXT`, it gives all columns concatenated together in string that is actually JSON.

Having this, you can get `md5` of all columns as follows:

```
SELECT md5(mytable::TEXT)
FROM mytable
```

If you want to only use some columns, use `ROW` constructor and cast it to `TEXT`:

```
SELECT md5(ROW(col1, col2, col3)::TEXT)
FROM mytable
```

Another nice property about this solution is that `md5` will be different for `NULL` vs. empty string.

Obligatory [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ab4bb/1).

Comment: just for the next person - no, this doesnt work with redshift.  redshift doesnt support the syntax (`# SELECT md5(precipitation::TEXT)
 from precipitation;
ERROR:  column "precipitation" does not exist in precipitation`)

Comment: @keen: redshift is based on very old version of postgresql. It works fine on postgresql 8.4+

Comment: Get the following error on Postgresql 8.2.15  ERROR: cannot cast type record to text

Comment: @Robinson: 8.2 is very old version - this syntax wasn't supported until version 8.4. I highly recommend upgrading to version 9.5 - it works lot faster, fixes many bugs and adds lots of new features.

Comment: Please use the syntax `md5(mytable.*::TEXT)` (note the `.*`). Otherwise if your table has a column called `mytable` the digest will be made only of this column.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use something else similar to mvp's solution. Instead of using ROW() function which is not supported by Amazon Redshift...

> Invalid operation: ROW expression, implicit or explicit, is not supported in target list;

My proposition is to use NVL2 and CAST function to cast different type of columns to CHAR, as long as this type is compatible with all Redshift data types according to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Type_conversion.html). Below there is an example of how to achieve *null proof* MD5 in Redshift.

```
SELECT md5(NVL2(col1,col1::char,''), 
           NVL2(col2,col2::char,''), 
           NVL2(col3,col3::char,''))
FROM mytable
```

This might work without casting second NVL2 function argument to char but it would definately fail if you'd try to get md5 from date column with null value.
I hope this would be helpful for someone.

Comment: This does not work for me on Redshift: "ERROR: function md5(text, text, text) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: @LotiLotiLoti specs of MD5 might have changed during that time. Try to wrap this one right now `md5( NVL2(col1,col1::char,'') || NVL2(col2,col2::char,'') || NVL2(col3,col3::char,'') )`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [CONCAT()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)? I just tried in my PG 9.1 install:

```
SELECT CONCAT('aaaa',1111,'bbbb');     => aaaa1111bbbb
SELECT CONCAT('aaaa',null,'bbbb');     => aaaabbbb
```

Therefore, you can try:

```
SELECT MD5(CONCAT(column1, column2, column3, column_n))    => md5_hash string here
```

Comment: This solution will give exact same md5 for `NULL` and for empty strings - probably not what you want.

Comment: Is there a way to change the accepted answer to mvp? That solution is far more elegant.

Comment: @UnderNewManagement: Only the OP can change that. See [this related question on meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/allow-author-of-accepted-answer-to-delete-it-in-certain-circumstances). I suppose you could add a note referring to the superior answer.

Comment: ok, selected answer goes to mvp; however, to be honest I do want to treat null and empty string the same in my case. I thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

select MD5(cast(p as text)) from fiscal_cfop as p