# I need assign all activities in SQL to one ID, but currently each activity has three id

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say that we have `views` table where each activity has three user ID.

- ID1 - user cookie on the server side
- ID2 - user cookie on the browser side
- ID3 - logged in user

I need to assign activity to one id.

Example:

```
ID1 ID2 ID3
-----------
1   A    
1   A
1   B    I
2   B    I
3   C    I
```

During the third activity, user registered account and now I know that all activity concern one user. ID1 and ID2 are cookies ID which are uncertain. ID3 is only when user is registered and logged in. Users don't have to be registered and logged. Users can use the site without an account - but I need information about the whole users activities.

1. How can I count all views and assing to one ID?
   In the above example we can see that 5 views were generated by one user.
2. Is it possible to JOIN another table having the same three ID?

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: User ID, number of views (count(views)).

In the above example we can see that one user visited page 5 times, and I'm thinking how can I code this in SQL.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: And how do you know those three rows belong to the same user? And if `id3` is the "user id", then I only see **one** page view: page `B` - not five  (and page `A` was visited by an unknown user)

Comment: ID1 and ID2 are cookies ID which are uncertain. ID3 is only when user is registered and logged in. Users don't have to be registered and logged. Users can use the site without an account - but I need information about the whole users.

Comment: So how do you know the first two rows belong to the last three rows?

Comment: Look at third row in table. We have ID1 = 1 and ID3 = I - which covers all rows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question correctly but could it look like that :

`SELECT ID3 AS "User ID", COUNT(*) AS "Number of views" FROM VIEWS GROUP BY ID3`

Comment: This way only 3 views will be counted.
We lost information about the user before registration.

Comment: Ok then I didn't understand the question. I would have add a comment instead of a botched answer but I don't have enough reputation yet

Comment: @brtk As I read through the question's comments, you may want to make an `UNION` between my answer and the same query using not `ID3` but one of the cookie (`ID2` maybe, you know better which of the 2 is the more relevant). Thus the column `User ID` would contain both registered users and cookies (unregistered).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to play a bit with it but cannot achieve what you want (limited time)

Two solution I think you can work with:

- window functions `SELECT gen_random_uuid(), count(id1) over (partition by ...)`
- union

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a sequential id using `dense_rank()`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by id1, id2, id3) as my_id
from t;
```

And you can join to another table, but be careful because of `NULL` values.  The first column always appears to be filled, so:

```
select . . .
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id1 = t2.id1 and
        t1.id2 is not distinct from t2.id2 and
        t2.id3 is not distinct from t3.id3
```

The only caveat is that `is not distinct from` does not work well with indexes, so this might be slower than you expect on a larger table.  If that is an issue, ask a *new* question.  This has gotten pretty far from your original question.

EDIT:

After reflecting on this problem, you have a graph problem with three possible connectors.  You should assign a unique id to each row in your original data.  Then you can use a recursive CTE to solve this.

Here is how:

```
with recursive ids as (
      select *
      from (values (1, 1, 'A', NULL),
                   (2, 1, 'A', NULL),
                   (3, 1, 'B', 'I'),
                   (4, 2, 'B', 'I'),
                   (5, 3, 'C', 'I'),
                   (6, 5, NULL, NULL)
           ) v(id, id1, id2, id3)
     ),
     pairs as (
      select distinct a.id as ida, b.id as idb
      from ids a join
           ids b
           on a.id1 = b.id1 or a.id2 = b.id2 or a.id3 = b.id3
     ),
     cte as (
      select  ida as ida, idb as idb, array[ida] as ids, 1 as lev
      from pairs
      union all
      select cte.ida, pairs.idb, cte.ids || pairs.ida, lev + 1
      from cte join
           pairs
           on cte.idb = pairs.ida and
              not cte.ids @> array[pairs.ida]
     )
select distinct on (ida) cte.*
from cte
order by ida, idb ;
```

This adds a new column `id` which is the unique id for each row.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8e2b4ec46883c078711ea99542079676) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you can [hash the columns together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576010/how-to-md5-all-columns-regardless-of-type) to form a distinct key for any 3 combinations

example in the link.